# Python - Comparing two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Comparing two Dataframes // Deciphering one Dataframe with another**

Hello everyone and thanks for the help!

I have two dataframes. The first (df1) contains all my data, including a column with a long list of abbreviations (df1[ab]) which i want to  translate into numbers via the second dataframe (df2). df2 contains two columns, one column with the same abbreviations (df2[key]) and one column with the related numbers (df2[value]).

My goal is to use the second dataframe as a deciphering tool for the first. I want to compare df1[ab] with df2[key] and create a new column in df1 which contains the correct numbers from df2[value] in the right order. Since the real list of abbreviations is quite long, i dont want to use a large number of "if-statements" to complete this task.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

abbreviations = ["Sl2","Sl4","Ss","Tu4","Slu","Su2/Su3","Ut2", "Ss","Sl2","Slu","Slu"]
dictab = {"ab": abbreviations}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dictab)

key = ["Ss","Sl2","Sl3","Sl4","Slu"]
value = [11,25,27,30,33]
dictkv = {"key":key, "value":value}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dictkv)
```

As a result, df1 should contain a new column df1[result] which should contain the following values in the following order:

```
print(df1)
         ab   result
0       Sl2       25 
1       Sl4       30
2        Ss       11
3       Tu4      NaN
4       Slu       33
5   Su2/Su3      NaN
6       Ut2      NaN
7        Ss       11
8       Sl2       25
9       Slu       33
10      Slu       33
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers, Jato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the additional column:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='ab', right_on='key', how='left')
```

Output

```
         ab  key    value
0       Sl2  Sl2    25.0
1       Sl4  Sl4    30.0
2        Ss  Ss     11.0
3       Tu4  NaN     NaN
4       Slu  Slu    33.0
5   Su2/Su3  NaN     NaN
6       Ut2  NaN     NaN
7        Ss  Ss     11.0
8       Sl2  Sl2    25.0
9       Slu  Slu    33.0
10      Slu  Slu    33.0
```

If you want the array of matches:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='ab', right_on='key', how='left').value.values
```

Output

```
array([25., 30., 11., nan, 33., nan, nan, 11., 25., 33., 33.])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response! You solved my problem in a matter of minutes ^^